# WebApi and MVC authentication in the same project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, oauth, hangfire

I'm trying to search for an answer since yesterday and until now no luck unfortunately.

We have a WebApi backend with frontEnd written in Angular2.

Authentication is created with the use of JWT Tokens.

So basically user makes a call to WebApi and obtains the Authentication token that stores some other info like Roles in Claims.

In the same project there are other things we'd like to include with very limited functionality so there is no need to separate them to another project like: small MVC app, HangFire, Elmah etc.

How can we authorize those apps ? Is it possible to use the JWT token obtained from WebApi ? If I understand correctly MVC and WebApi exist in different contexts.